# How to get started with express and nuxt/viue for this default setting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server, client, nuxt.js

How do I get to work following sample of code:

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready()
  }

  app.get('/route', (req, res) => { // i test this, but failed
    res.json({ message: 'yes' }) // then on .vue feel i use axios to get this localhost
   })

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

Should I create some router inside the start function? How to export them in nuxt and get the data in the .vue file?

Comment: Do you want to use express as an API to retrieve data?

Comment: yes, i have tried till now, but not working

Comment: and if you go to `localhost:3000/route` do get the data that's supposed?

Comment: yes on my localhost/router i set data message as yes, then  on my home, i render it with axios, and i got that data on my localhost:300 by nuxt, but when i go to  localhost/route , that route respont that message,

Comment: i want tp create router on express like this /mynuxt , and then on router nuxt , i want to set up /mynuxt , is that possible? and how?

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options put togheter express and Nuxt, making live express in the server directory or use nuxt pure as frontend (awesomesite.com) and express pure as api (api.awesomesite.com), in any of the two cases the life is more easy if you use axios and configure them in your nuxt.config.js file,

```
 axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.AXIOS_SERVER
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },
```

after that you use axios as usual in your components to communicate with the server side.

I thing you try to use express embed with nuxt. To do that i prefers create a structure inside server directory

```
/server
  /router
   index.js
  index.js
  globals.js
```

router/index.js

```
const router = require('express').Router()

router.post('/your-route', function (req, res, next) {
  //todo this route
});
router.post('/other-route', function (req, res, next) {
  //todo this route
});
module.exports.router = router;
```

server/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()
{ router } = require('./router') //the router!!!

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
app.use('/', router) // '/' or '/api' depends to you

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready()
  }


  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

in a vue component you can use AXIOS simply like that:

```
  methods: {
    async send() {
      this.waiting = true
      await this.$axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/your-route',
        data: this.form
      })
        .then(res => {
          this.success = true
          this.error = false
          this.onReset()
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.error = true
          this.success = false
        })
      this.waiting = false
    }
}
```

Comment: so i dont need to change any data in server/index? and then create own router by new folder on server folder ? is that corect? how to run awesomesite.com then ??

Comment: what is folder for globlas.js for ?

Comment: ups i forget to delete them, usually I create a class globals inside global.js with common funtions i will use in multiples parts of my server, but you are not obligate to use them

Comment: In production I prefers use nginx as reverse proxy, with let's encrypt. it<s really easy, more info in this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-node-js-application-with-docker

Comment: @Pablote
So you mean if I have `router.get('/hello', callback)`, and I accessed it from the browser `https://localhost:3000/hello` It should work? I'm asking because I cannot get it work same as you did, and I see only from internet to use internal express as API I shall use serverMiddleware, what do you think I am missing?

Comment: @AhmedShendy it works, you need set a server response in your callback, but the get will bypass nuxt, to avoid this you should use a server middleware